# Last item of ForEach comes undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, express, strongloop

here is my code:

```
useraccountprofileJSON.providerprofile.openinginfo.forEach(function(instance_1){
                                    instance_1.openingdetail.openingapplication.forEach(function(instance_2){
                                        console.log(instance_2);
                                        if(instance_2.oaid == oaid){
                                            isowner = true;
                                        }
                                    });
                                });
```

When I execute this I get the following error:

> [TypeError: Cannot read property 'openingapplication' of undefined]

The error is because the last item(i.e last openingdetail) comes undefined in forEach iterations.

How to solve this?

Comment: Not include the `undefined` in your array (best solution), or simply check using `if(instance1){ ... }`

Comment: undefined is not in any of my values!

Comment: But `forEach` is not _making it up_ either. It has to be there. Could you show the JSON and potentially the input / output of the JSON?

Comment: first `console.log()` your `instance_1` whether its getting `openingdetail` property or not. You are getting this undefined as `openingdetail` key is not available in your `instance_1`.

Comment: @AjitejKaushik Yah, last item in instance_1 does not getting me openingdetail. Thats my point. Why isn't it showing me up even if its exists in database. It happens only to last item.

Comment: It may happen that some of your collection may contain `openingdetail` and some may not, thatswhy you will may get this error, refer your tables and see there must be a conflict in data.

Answer (score 0):

You can work around this, by replacing:

```
instance_1.openingdetail.openingapplication.forEach
```

with:

```
instance_1.openingdetail && instance_1.openingdetail.openingapplication.forEach
```

#### Remark

If the purpose of your code is just to set the `isowner` value, then you can use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), which will exit as soon as it finds one `oid` match:

```
isowner = useraccountprofileJSON.providerprofile.openinginfo.some(function(instance_1){
    return instance_1.openingdetail && 
           instance_1.openingdetail.openingapplication.some(function(instance_2){
        return instance_2.oaid == oaid;
    });
});
```